# Posting data to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using JSON and jQuery to make an asynchronous post back to controller.

Code in view:

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Class1

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
    {
        $('.remove').click(function ()
        {
            alert('Buton Clicked');  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "/Default1Controller/RemoveItem/",  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                data: "{}",  
                dataType: "json",  
                success: removeItemCompleted,  
                error: removeItemFailed  
            });      
        });  

        function removeItemCompleted(results)
        {
            alert('SUCCESS');
        }

        function removeItemFailed(request, status, error)
        {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });

</script>

<h2>Index</h2>
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="Text2" type="text" />
<input id="Text3" type="text" />
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit"  class="remove" />
```

Code in controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default1/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RemoveItem()
        {
            return Json(new { Status = 1, Message = "Success" });
        }
    }
}
```

When the HTML button is clicked, the controller event is not getting called.

Anyone know the issue in above code?

Comment: You have no form  here, how do you expect to post without it

Comment: I think the url should be "/Default1/RemoveItem/"

Comment: check with firebug or ie developer toolbar on the net tab what's happening

Comment: "/Default1/RemoveItem/" ---- here  "Default1Controller" it should be  controller name ??? is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: @(Url.Action("RemoveItem", "Default1")),  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            data: "{}",  
            dataType: "json",  
            success: removeItemCompleted,  
            error: removeItemFailed  
        });
```

Comment: it is posting,but, here , but url: "@(Url.Action("RemoveItem", "Default1"))", "Default1" is controller name???

Comment: yes, in MVC when your controller class name is "BlaBlaBlaController" its name is "BlaBlaBla".

Comment: also try to use MVC build-in helpers instead of hard coded strings. IE. HTML.ActionLink, Url.Action and so on.